# How to revert the transformation done by openface.AlignDlib.align?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I'm new to [openface](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/). I know how to get an aligned face using openface.AlignDlib.align(), but is there anyway to transform the face back to its original shape?

Comment: how is it different from keeping `rgbImg` you pass to `.align()`?

Comment: Just curious, what does your question have anything to do with opencv?

Comment: @Marat: let's say i made some modification to the aligned image and i want to keep that modification when I get back to the original rbgImg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically need is an inverse affine transformation. So, we need to get an inverse transformation matrix, and then apply `warpAffine`. Here is a piece of `align()` [code](http://openface-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/openface/align_dlib.html#AlignDlib.align):

```
npLandmarkIndices = np.array(landmarkIndices)
H = cv2.getAffineTransform(npLandmarks[npLandmarkIndices],
                               imgDim * MINMAX_TEMPLATE[npLandmarkIndices])
thumbnail = cv2.warpAffine(rgbImg, H, (imgDim, imgDim))
```

`H` is not stored anywhere, so we need to learn the transform matrix:

```
H_reverse = cv2.getAffineTransform(
    imgDim * MINMAX_TEMPLATE[npLandmarkIndices], 
    npLandmarks[npLandmarkIndices])
inverse_projection = cv2.warpAffine(thumbnail, H_reverse, rgbImg.shape)
```

I did not check if the code is actually working, but I hope you can get the direction